# How to stage specific lines to git

Tags: bash, git, shell, awk

I want to be able stage specific lines of code that match a pattern (`MARKETING_VERSION` in my case).

I've got the awk command which will show me the lines that match the pattern `MARKETING_VERSION` but I don't know how to stage the lines from that result to git.

`awk '/MARKETING_VERSION/{print NR}' exampleFile.txt`
the result in terminal is

```
1191
1245
```

How can I use this result to stage those specific lines in that file to git?

I know you can use `git add -p` but I want to use this in a shell script so I need a non-interactive version.

TIA